# Why is "victuals" pronounced "vittles"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

This doesn't make sense to me.  Is it just laziness?

Comment: If that is the way Queen Elizabeth pronounces it, that is good enough for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/victuals):

> Word Origin & History
>
> **victuals**
>
> c.1300, vitaylle  (singular), from Anglo-Fr. and O.Fr. vitaille,  from L.L. victualia  "provisions," noun use of plural of victualis  "of nourishment," from victus  "livelihood, food, sustenance," from base of vivere  "to live" (see vital). Spelling altered early 16c. to conform with Latin, but pronunciation remains "vittles."

*Vitaille* had no "c", and hence its English form was pronounced "vittle". Only later was the "c" added.

Comment: Mine was a crap answer, you're right.

Comment: A little out of the way here, @drm65, but why was 'c' added?

Comment: >Spelling altered early 16c. to conform with Latin, but pronunciation remains "vittles."  I don't know why someone decided to conform to the Latin spelling.

Comment: It's called a *false etymology* -- essentially, some scholar along the way missed the intervening few hundred years of French (and, one would suppose, Proto-Romance) usage and assumed it came from the Latin more directly. A surprisingly large number of English spellings are back-formed this way; *victuals* is actually more correct than most since it *can* eventually be traced back to *victus*. A lot of false etymologies are nothing more than coincidence.

Comment: Early linguists tended to be Latin scholars, and thought all languages should have rules similar to Latin's. This is the source of all kinds of sillyness, like the supposed rule that setences should not end with prepositions, or infinitives should not be "split".

Comment: silent c: indict, victuals, arctic; silent p: receipt; silent s: isle, island; silent b: debt, doubt, subtle. All these have to do with 16th century zeal for etymological explanations.

Comment: @RainDoctor _Arctic_ doesn't have a silent c for me (or anyone else I've heard say the word).