# How is "victualling" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

[*Victuals* is famously pronounced "vittles"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33213/why-is-victuals-pronounced-vittles).  But how is *victualling*, as in [victualling yard](https://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/heritageapp/ViewHeritageItemDetails.aspx?ID=5054717), pronounced?

I presume the "c" remains silent, but various unsourced and presumably autogenerated pronunciation videos suggest both "[vittling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbIdOzkM3DE)" and "[vittualing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIa7J7p9MyM)".

Comment: Haha, cool question. I’ve heard it in older TV shows and movies (where the Hollywood actors were perforce affecting a Appalachian or otherwise rural accent, not necessarily faithfully!) as the former, *vitt’lin*.

Comment: Of course single *l* for American spelling ... *victualing*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/ˈvɪtlɪŋ/, i.e. the normal pronunciation of *victual* + *-ing*.

*Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary*, 18th ed.:
[image: Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary*, 18th ed]

*The Routledge Dictionary of Pronunciation for Current English*, 2nd ed.:
[image: The Routledge Dictionary of Pronunciation for Current English, 2nd ed.]

Comment: Not /ˈvɪtəlɪŋ/, with three syllables? That's how it's pronounced on [forvo.com](https://forvo.com/word/victualling/#en). Same for *whittling* and *belittling*. Also, the OP's first video pronounces it this way. Do you have any actual evidence it's pronounced with two syllables *vit-ling* /ˈvɪtlɪŋ/,? Your dictionary pronunciations seem ambiguous to me.

Comment: @PeterShor As seen in the dictionaries, /l/ here is a syllabic consonant and interchangeable with /əl/. In *victual(s/ed)* it constitutes a syllable by itself, but in *victual(l)ing* it may be absorbed by the following syllable (*-ing*) – [a phenomenon John Wells calls "compression"](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2011/12/more-syllabic-consonants.html).

Comment: Then you shouldn't use /ˈvɪtlɪŋ/ but /ˈvɪtl̩iŋ/ (with a dot under the *l*  or /ˈvɪt.l.ɪŋ/ with explicit syllable breaks. I don't think *whittle* and *belittle* undergo compression very often in English (unlike *power* and *trouble*). Certainly not in American English, because then you would have to turn a flapped /t/ back into a real /t/, which I think we almost never do here.

Comment: @PeterShor But it can be either two or three syllables. Which is why I deliberately chose not to indicate syllabicity or syllabification, which are by no means mandatory. Compression into /tl/ may be less common, but certainly not impossible. See Merriam-Webster's entry for [*bottling*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bottling), for example.

Answer (score 4):

The *OED* says /ˈvɪt(ə)lɪŋ/ showing the extra syllable is optional. Their recorded pronunciation does have the schwa in there.