# Is there a distinction between “victuals” and “vittles” that exists in writing but not in speech?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, dictionaries, eye-dialect

As I set out on this project I noticed that there are already several questions at EL&U referring to the words here in question. But what can I do?

In [Merriam-Webster’s entry for *victuals*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/victual), it is remarked that the word *vittles* “sounds like it might be an alteration of the plural *victuals* but… actually entered English a century before *victual*.”

But [their entry for *vittles*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vittles) defines *vittles* as “VICTUALS -- now chiefly used playfully to evoke the supposed language of cowboys.” The two entries give the same pronunciation.

I feel like I’m missing something here, but I’m not totally sure what that is. Please find my confusion.

Now as always, there’s only one word, with one pronunciation (rhyming with *belittles*) and one meaning (food). During the 14th Century the spelling was *vittles*, but ever since, the normal spelling has been *victuals*.

Today in spoken English the only form still rhymes with *belittles*. So although when I pronounce it in the only correct way I feel like I’m playfully evoking the language of [Jed Clampett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beverly_Hillbillies#J._D._%22Jed%22_Clampett), and I’d much rather say VIK-chew-alls, that’s all just the craziness in my mind. The only distinction is in the writing.

When writing we have the option of spelling it either *victuals* or *vittles*, making the second choice when we want playfully to evoke the supposed language of cowboys. As the excerpts in the Merriam-Webster entries seem to show, the writers who intend a light touch spell it phonetically, and the tonier writers spell it with the silent *c*.

**ON THE ONE HAND: VICTUALS**

- the navy was usually equipped, clothed and victualled by the Crown
- that evening the travelers victualed sumptuously on partridge and venison
- Or, just buy a bottle and some victuals from the on-site shop, and get in on the picnic action yourself.
  — Kristin Luna, Condé Nast Traveler, "3 Best Day Trips from Nashville," 4 Mar. 2018
- Scholars long thought that the capability to construct and victual a watercraft and then navigate it to a distant coast arrived only with advent of agriculture and animal domestication.
  — Andrew Lawler, Science | AAAS, "Neandertals, Stone Age people may have voyaged the Mediterranean," 24 Apr. 2018

**ON THE OTHER HAND: VITTLES**

- The vendors sold souvenirs and knickknacks and all manner of local vittles.
  — Frank Deford
- Taco Cabana of San Antonio makes sure its vittles are the freshest Tex-Mex north of the Rio Grande.
  — Richard S. Teitelbaum
- My mother turned an icy stare on her, leaving my father to try to make amends. "All you kids have to stay for dinner. Leo and I'll rustle up some vittles." "Vittles?" my mother asked with disdain. "Food," my father said. "In cowboy movies, they call it vittles." "I abhor cowboy movies," she said, and returned to her room.
  — Pat Conroy
- There's a caterer's kitchen with its own entrance, and a dumbwaiter for the vittles and drinks.
  — Rohan Preston Star Tribune, Star Tribune, "$1.5M Eden Prairie luxury home is a stargazer's delight," 11 Dec. 2020
- But viral and bacterial genetic material didn’t always track together, Brown said, hinting that some protists might have skipped the middleman and gone straight for the viral vittles.
  — Katherine J. Wu New York Times, Star Tribune, "Nothing eats viruses, right? Meet some hungry protists," 24 Sep. 2020

**SOME REFLECTIONS ON THE FIRST FEW DAYS' ACTIVITY**

The discussion so far makes me wonder: what sort of a pair of words are victuals and vittles?

1. They are simply two spellings for one word, both correct, with no other difference in pronunciation or meaning. Colorizing and colourising are in this class. My trouble with this theory is that (1) the Merriam-Webster definitions don’t seem to read this way, associating only one word with cowboys and providing a second full entry instead of just redirecting to the first entry, (2) the cited examples seem to associate victuals with a higher tone than vittles, and (3) where the writing reports a spoken conversation, the high tone of victuals and the low tone of vittles would seem to require a different pronunciation.
2. They are two spellings for one word, one correct and one incorrect, with no other difference in pronunciation or meaning. Writing nolij for an ignorant speaker’s correct pronunciation of knowledge would typify this group. My problems here are the three cited above, but also that (4) Merriam-Webster does not disparage either spelling, victuals or vittles, and (5) in the quoted instances neither word appears beside whimsical misspellings, like “We wuz skinny cuzza dey’d alwayz gave us widdle enuf viddles to keep us alives." whimsical misspellings which would apparently support the characterization of vittles as aye-dialick, a spelling that records a correct pronunciation amidst a generally inferior English style.
3. They are two spellings of one word, reflecting less refined and more refined pronunciations. Britches (vs. breeches), crick (vs. creek), critter (vs. creature), dawg (vs. dog), me (meaning 'my,' vs. my), pardner (vs. partner), weskit (vs. waistcoat), and wittles (vs. victuals and vittles), exemplify this possibility, because the nonparenthetical spelling suggests a worse pronunciation. My problem here is that Merriam-Webster does not indicate any difference in pronunciation.
4. They are two spellings of one word, reflecting two acceptable pronunciations. In this class are words like wander'd and burnish'd, where the apostrophe indicates very little stress on that final vowel, distinct from the heavily stressed final vowel when actors say for Romeo "banished" or for Hamlet "damned.” Again, Merriam-Webster does not indicate any difference in pronunciation.

So it feels like something's got to give.

Comment: Why did people start spelling it *victuals*? The word [*vittles*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/victuals) was derived (via French) from the Latin word *victualia*, with a "c". In the 15th and 16th centuries,  pedants tried to add back letters that had been dropped from the Latin form, so we now spell *iland* with a silent "s", *dette* with a silent "b", and *vittles* with a silent "c".

Comment: [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vittles) says 'vittles' is a non-standard variant of 'victuals'. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/vittle) marks it *archaic*.

Comment: It's like spelling 'breeches' as 'britches' (the usual pronunciation) and 'waistcoat' as 'weskit' (an old-fashioned alternative pronunciation). Sometimes such spellings are used to represent uneducated speech. In Patrick O'Brian's historical novels, Captain Aubrey's uncouth servant often announces "Wittles is up" when dinner is ready.

Comment: @Kate Bunting If the character is pronouncing the words "breeches" and "waistcoat" correctly, in the normal ways normally spelled as I just spelled them, then what does the author communicate by changing the spelling?

Comment: @Kate Bunting In other words, I feel like your examples are an attempt to record an alternative pronunciation by a variation in spelling, while my original examples share only one pronunciation.

Comment: There used to be a convention of spelling some words 'phonetically' when portraying the speech of a 'lower-class' character, even when some of those spellings actually represent the standard pronunciation.

Comment: @Chaim: The spelling *wittles* is not the usual pronunciation (note the "w" at the front). Dickens used *wittles* in Magwitch's speech in *Great Expectations*, although most of the time he spelled it *victuals*.

Comment: @Peter Shor So we're all agreed that spelling variations like "wittles" often represent mispronunciation, while "victuals" and "vittles" represent the same correct pronunciation.

Comment: @Chaim: for *britches* and *breeches*, there are [two acceptable pronunciations.](https://www.lexico.com/definition/breeches) Spelling it *britches* specifies which one a character uses, which might indicate something about their dialect. For *victuals*, those authors that spell it *vittles* might be under the misapprehension that there are two acceptable pronunciations for it.

Comment: Something similar confused me when I was a child. I read books with the spelling *dawg*, and I wondered vaguely how else you could possibly pronounce the word. [Since then, I've learned from 19th-century dictionaries that in the 19th and early 20th centuries, and /dɑɡ/ was the "proper" pronunciation and /dɔɡ/ was a dialectical pronunciation, but since then /dɔɡ/ has become more or less standard.]

Comment: @Peter Shor I assume that "dawg" makes "daw" rhyme with "how" or "now," followed by the hard "g" sound. But it's strange to think that the use of "vittles," almost as common as "victuals" in American writing (according to an answer by linguisticturn), reflect the widespread failure to do what I did today, viz. to look them up in the dictionary and find that they're pronounced alike.

Comment: According to *Merriam-Webster,* *vittles* is **not** a deliberate misspelling of *victuals*. See the quote I just added to my answer, [below](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/560246/155553). (It turns out that *vittles* entered English a century before *victual*.)

Comment: According to [CulinaryLore](https://culinarylore.com/food-history:vittles-origin/), ***vittles*** is simply a *vulgar misspelling* of ***victuals***.

Comment: @Peter Shor I clearly need to try again to clarify my question. But your comment reminds me of a conversation I once had while discussing Locksley Hall by Tennyson. Words like wander'd and burnish'd puzzled me; how was I supposed to change the normal sound? Someone suggested that Tennyson was trying to discourage the stressing of that final vowel that actors often stress in Shakespeare, in Romeo's "banished" and Hamlet's "damned," for example. I think our copy also showed stresses on syllables that we would all have stressed anyhow, although I cannot now find anything like that on the web.

Comment: @PeterShor Not just *dawg* but *hawg* too, as in [Milwaukee’s **Hole Hawg** referenced by Neal Stephenson](http://www.team.net/mjb/hawg.html) when he called Unix the Hole Hawg of operating systems. :)  I have yet to notice *lawg, bawg, faug, frawg, slawg, jawg, smawg* for *log, bog, fog, frog, slog, jog, smog* to go with *hawg* and *dawg*, but those others wouldn't surprise me much if I did.

Comment: @KateBunting That seems exactly like how we sometimes use the eye-dialect spelling of *crick* for *creek* in speakers who have a short vowel there not a long one even though it is the same word. Also how we sometimes still represent the unstressed /mi/ pronunciation of *my* common in some UK speakers as if it were  really spelled *me* even though it is not and even though they aren't saying that word but *my*; it just sounds like *me* not /mai/ for want of stress. These are the same words, not different ones. The eye-dialect spellings though have confused people about them.

Comment: @Chaim: In Shakespeare's time, there were two common pronunciations of most past tenses, and Shakespeare used *stain'd* when he wanted a one-syllable pronunciation and *stained* when he wanted a two-syllable one, so his poetry would scan. By Tennyson's time, I think *stain'd* was the only pronunciation that anybody but poets used, but poets (at least some of them) found it so convenient to be able to put in the extra syllable that they kept using this convention.

Comment: @tchrist: Personally, I say *dawg, hawg, lawg, frawg, bawg, fawg, smawg,* and use that vowel for pretty much all "-og" words except for *cog* and *eggnog*. I don't know why these two are exceptions, but [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cog) agrees with me about their pronunciations.

Comment: When both spellings are acceptable and the meaning is the same, use the one that "sounds out" like it is pronounced. You don't get extra points for making people feel stupid for sounding out *victuals* and pronouncing it wrong. Cf. *forecastle* — pronounced *foke-səl* — alternatively spelled *fo'c'sle* for clarity.

Comment: Related: _critter_ and _creature._

Comment: @PeterShor Ah, the perils of learning English from someone with the cot/caught merger. At any rate, for those who do not have that merger, their speech is not thereby non-standard.

Answer (score 11):

Spelling and pronunciation do not necessarily correspond to one another in English. This difference of spelling emerges in the early modern period.

*Victuals* ([OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/223242)) has had a number of spellings in Middle English, usually with *vit*- or *vyt*-. These spellings were closer to the Anglo-Norman spelling *vitaile*. As Middle English spelling is largely phonetic, forms with *vit*- and *vyt*- were also pronounced with a /t/.

As English spelling began to standardize in the early modern period, sometimes spellings would change to reflect concerns beyond pronunciation, like perceived etymology. In this case, *victual* in spelling assimilated the spelling of an older Latin cognate (*victus*, food) while retaining the older pronunciation. These spellings are evident in lexicons as early as *[An Alveary or Triple Dictionary, in English, Latin, and French](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/127/3343)* (John Baret, 1574):

> - Pertayning to meate or victual: also base: simple.

Meanwhile, the *vit*- form persisted and eventually became *vittle*. It appears in some early lexicons, like Richard Mulcaster's *[The First Part of the Elementary](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/164/7472)* (1582) (*vitail*), but most lexicons thereafter default to *vict*-, and *victual* is the standard spelling in Samuel Johnson's 1755 *[Dictionary](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/1345/39348)*. *Vittle* was preserved as a dialectal usage, which was useful for representing nonstandard speakers or informal usage in writing:

> I must confess your wine and *vittle* / I was too hard upon a little (Jonathan Swift, "[Stella at Wood Park](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/13621/13621-h/13621-h.htm)," 1723.)

> He was drunk, and weaving about in his saddle; he was over fifty year old, and had a very red face. Everybody yelled at him and laughed at him and sassed him, and he sassed back, and said he’d attend to them and lay them out in their regular turns, but he couldn’t wait now because he’d come to town to kill old Colonel Sherburn, and his motto was, “Meat first, and spoon *vittles* to top off on.” (*[Huckleberry Finn](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-h/76-h.htm#c34-293)*, Mark Twain, 1885)

Answer (score 9):

*Is there a distinction between “victuals” and “vittles” that exists in writing but not in speech?* I think the short answer is **yes.** However, it's not a difference in the connotation of *that single word*, the way there's a distinction between, say, "terse" and "curt." These two spellings belong to completely different registers.

> When writing we have the option of spelling it either *victuals* or *vittles*, making the second choice when we want playfully to evoke the supposed language of cowboys. As the excerpts in the Merriam-Webster entries seem to show, the writers who intend a light touch spell it phonetically, and the tonier writers spell it with the silent c.

Right. Except that there's another difference:

*Victual* can be a verb, synonymous with "provision." **Victual, victuals, victualled, victualling.** We see this verb form in three of your four example sentences. I claim that these writers had no choice, because...

*Vittles* is ***only ever*** a plural/mass noun, as far as I'm concerned. ***Vittle, *vittles, *vittled, *vittling.** ("What are you doing with that knife, Herr Wagner?")

You can victual your ship or your army, but you cannot "vittle" it. Load up the chuck wagon *with* vittles, yes. *Vittle the chuck wagon, no.

You can invite your epicurean acquaintance to victual with you (come on over! we'll tear a bird together!), but you cannot invite them to "vittle" with you. Chow down *on* some tender vittles, yes. *Vittle on chicken wings and beer, no.

Basically, "vittles" is a noun for cowboys; "victual" is a verb for military historians, a noun for Ren Faire attendees, and both for pretentious gastronauts.

N.B.: There is no non-loaded spelling of this word. If you want to refer to "vittles" without sounding like a cowboy, you don't write "victuals"; you write "food"!

By the way, [How is "victualling" pronounced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/467605/how-is-victualling-pronounced) — I didn't know this myself. I would have guessed "vittling" and "viktyueling" with about equal probability, tending toward the latter (and wrong) pronunciation.

Comment: Pretty sure it either rhymes with *fiddling* or with *purple*. :)

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be an American vs. British English issue.

For one thing, the *Oxford English Dictionary* doesn't have an entry for *vittles*, though it does for *victuals*.

For another, in the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), there are 126 hits for *victuals* and 117 for *vittles.*

In contrast, in the *British National Corpus* [(BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/), there are 25 hits for *victuals* and **none** for *vittles.*

As far as your question about whether there is any difference in meaning, you basically answered your own question: no, there is no difference in meaning, but there might one of **register,** namely, *vittles* is more informal and humorous.

***Vittles* not a deliberate misspelling of *victuals***

There is some suggestion in the comments and the other answers that *vittles* is a deliberate misspelling of *victuals* that matches the pronunciation of the latter more closely. However, the following note from *Merriam-Webster* would seem to dispute that ([link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/victuals); scroll down):

> If you're hungry for the story behind victual, get ready to dig into a rich and fulfilling history. The word derives via Middle English and Anglo-French from the Latin noun *victus*, meaning "nourishment" or "way of living." *Victus* derives from the verb *vivere*, which means "to live" and which is the source of a whole smorgasbord of other English words like *vital*, *vivid*, and *survive*. It's also the root of *viand*, another English word referring to food. There's also ***vittles,*** a word that sounds like it might be an alteration of the plural *victuals* but which actually entered English a century before *victual*.

Comment: I again have déjà dit! The entire **point** of using [*aye-dialick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect) like this (meaning "words that are deliberately misspelled but properly pronounced") is because this way the writer "indicates that the character's speech overall is dialectal, foreign, or uneducated". So for example: *“We wuz skinny cuzza dey’d alwayz gave us widdle enuf viddles to keep us alives."*

Comment: @tchrist According to *Merriam-Webster,* *vittles* is **not** a deliberate misspelling of *victuals*. See the quote I just added to my answer, above.

Comment: Right. It's funny, but whatever I'm confused about here seems to be eluding this generous discussion. I see that you're contracting tchrist, but I don't think that you're contradicting me. The situation of two correct spellings, with one sound and meaning, but where one spelling is used playfully to evoke the supposed language of cowboys, is apparently unique to this case and just does not make sense to me. How does speech allow Pat Conroy's mother to recognize which spelling was used? That Merriam-Webster quotation is where my troubles began. I quoted it in the original question.

Comment: @Chaim Ah, yes, I thought I saw it quoted in your question, but then I couldn't find it…. and now I see it again. Now back to Pat Conroy. I seem to be missing something (again). The mother doesn't spell it, of course. She merely says it. The spelling is done only by the writer/narrator. And the writer/narrator knows that the father is using the 'cowboy' term, so that's the spelling that appears in text. If you want, at the time the mother says *Vittles?*, **she** doesn't have enough information to know whether it's *vittles* or *victuals*.  But the **writer/narrator** does.

Comment: I just don't follow that. What does it mean to say that the father is using the cowboy term? How is there a cowboy term when cowboys make exactly the same sound as everybody else, with exactly the same meaning? Would it be equally sensible to write "nolij" to record cowboy references to knowledge, so that if I mentioned knowledge around Pat Conroy's mother, she would object to the word when she knows I'm using the cowboy term but not otherwise?

Comment: @Chaim (Maybe [*pardner*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pardner) is a more standard example than *nolij*.) A couple of things to keep in mind. 1. *victuals* and *vittles* are, for most people, not very common words. In fact, many people would have heard ˈvi-​tᵊlz only in Western movies (and saw *vittles* only in Western novels). Western movies somehow decided that cowboys liked that word (I don't know if that had any basis in historical fact, but that is actually irrelevant for our purposes).

Comment: @Chaim  2. Furthermore, by the time of the writing of the scene with Pat Conroy's mother, there was presumably an established tradition of using the spelling *vittles* when reporting cowboy speech (how that tradition got started is a separate question).

Comment: @Chaim 3. There is no reason to think that the mother heard the word vi-​tᵊlz in any other context than Westerns. But even if she had, again, vi-​tᵊlz is rare in speech. She could have objected to its usage even before she learned that the father was referencing Westerns. Why use such an unusual word for *food*? It was clear to the mother that the father was going for some sort of effect, and she just wasn't in a mood for *any* effects. In other words, she probably would have sneered if the father was referencing something 'fancier', where the spelling *victuals* would have been standard.

Comment: @linguisticturn Or hillbillies not cowboys. I say this because they quite famously said *viddles* rhyming with *riddles* on [*The Beverly Hillbillies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beverly_Hillbillies).

Answer (score 1):

OED entry is only for "victual(s)", "vittles" does not have an entry. (The **victual** entry has not yet been fully updated (first published 1917).)

The result is "**vittles**" is the correct pronunciation of **victuals**, and thus
**vittles** is to **victuals** as **nolij** is to **knowledge**: a phonetic representation, although 'vittles' is more readily accepted.

> **victual**, n.
>
> Pronunciation:  Brit. /ˈvɪtl/,  U.S. /ˈvɪd(ə)l/
>
> Etymology: < Anglo-Norman and Old French vitaile, -aille (Old French also vitale , -alle, vittalle , victaille ) feminine < late Latin victuālia , neuter plural of post-classical Latin victuālis , < victus food, sustenance: (...) **The variant Old French and modern French form victuaille has been assimilated to the Latin original, and a similar change in spelling has been made in English, while the pronunciation still represents the forms vittel , vittle.**
>
> Forms:  (OE and most ME omitted) 1500s–1600s, 1700s–1800s dialect **vittle** (1600s victle), 1800s dialect **fittle, wittle**. ε. 1500s **wyttuel, wittual**, 1600s **vittual**, 1700s vitual; 1500s victuayle, Scottish wictuale, victuale, victwale, **victuel,victuell**, Middle English–1600s **victuall** (1500s **wictuall, wictwall**), 1500s vyctual, 1500s– **victual**
>
> **2.a. plural. Articles of food; supplies, or various kinds, of provisions; in later use esp. articles of ordinary diet prepared for use.**
>
> α.
>
> 1607   T. Dekker & J. Webster Famous Hist. Thomas Wyat sig. C3   *Good victailes makes good blood.*
>
> c1616   R. C. Times' Whistle (1871) vi. 2695   *Which I paide.., Because they should not think I came to sharke Only for vittailes.*
>
> δ.
>
> 1554–9   in T. Wright Songs & Ballads Philip & Mary (1860) (Roxb.) 12   *And dear cheape of vittels withe the thowe hast brought To the towne.
> *
> 1892   ‘Q’ I saw Three Ships vi. 106   *And so say I, wi' all these vittles cryin' out to be ate.*
>
> ε.
>
> 1523   T. Cromwell Speech to Parl. in R. B. Merriman Life & Lett. T. Cromwell (1902) I. 39   *As for victuaylys in our waye we shuld be sure none to fynde.*
>
> 1840   T. Hood Up Rhine 201   *It seems to me a very odd proceeding for..a town to lay a tax on the persons who bring it victuals.*
>
> 1866   C. Kingsley Hereward the Wake I. xv. 275   *There was..decking of the hall in the best hangings..; cooking of victuals, broaching of casks.*

Comment: But I don't think I've ever before seen anyone write "nolij." Why would anyone do that, if not to transcribe some change in sound? Whereas I've seen "vittles" many times, although apparently not to transcribe any change in sound.

Comment: I have déjà dit! The entire **point** of using [*aye-dialick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect) like this (meaning "words that are deliberately misspelled but properly pronounced") is because this way the writer "indicates that the character's speech overall is dialectal, foreign, or uneducated".

Comment: @Chaim English spelling is only loosely connected to pronunciation: who would have thought that the surname "Featherstonehaugh" was pronounced "Fanshore"? Why do we commonly see "phonetic" spellings in direct speech? Why is "one" not pronounced to rhyme with "lone"? Spelling mainly fossilised from the 18th century around the well-meaning, educated class's version of what English should be - and if that meant preference given to the Latin form - so be it. However the rest simply kept saying the word as they had always done.

Comment: @tchrist♦ I guess this is what Kate Bunting was describing, in her comment on my question. So apparently you two see this point, though I cannot see it. But when someone said "vittles" to Pat Conroy's mother, how did she know that he was not saying "victuals"? Is it because his speech overall is dialectal, foreign or uneducated? It seems to me that either (1) she objected to the word regardless of spelling or (2) she thought that pronunciation distinguished "vittles" from "vicutals."

Comment: *Merriam-Webster* disputes that *vittles* is a deliberate misspelling of *victuals*. That dictionary says that *vittles* entered English a century before *victuals*. See [my answer on this page](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/560246/155553).

Comment: @linguisticturn The earliest OED references for **vittle** is 1303   *Handlyng Synne 10555  "Y was wunt to lede **vytayle** To knyȝtes þat were yn batayle."* and for **victual** 1523  *T. Cromwell Speech to Parl. I. 39  "The Frenche men..lye yn wayte..to destroye the Conductours of our **victuayle.*** I'm a little lost: Are you saying that there was a word "**vittle**" and a new word was coined **victual** alongside it, that was so similar that people pronounced it the same?  What don't you like about the OED etymology above?

Comment: @Greybeard It does seem that *Merriam-Webster* and *OED* disagree about whether *vittles* and *victuals* are the same word. The *OED* is clearly implying they are the same word spelled in two different ways. *Merriam-Webster,* in contrast, says this (in a note about *victuals*): *there's also* **vittles,** *a word that sounds like it might be an alteration of the plural* **victuals** *but which actually entered English a century before* victual.

Comment: @Greybeard Obviously, I don't know who's right. All I can say is that the *OED* is not infallible, since I can point to examples in the *OED* where the etymologies given for different words make inconsistent claims. (It goes without saying that the *Merriam-Webster* is not infallible, either.)

Comment: @Chaim Much of the confusion about what the OED is actually saying derives from not reading [the full text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMXp9.png).  Please read the history of forms very carefully: those are all the same word despite the myriad spellings. This is just like how *colorizing* and *colourising* are still the same word.

Comment: @linguisticturn *(It goes without saying that the Merriam-Webster is not infallible, either.)* MW - Mostly Wrong :)